# Is this definition of work right?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, definition

My thermodynamics textbook defines [work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_%28thermodynamics%29) as follows.

> Work is motion against an opposing force.

But this definition of work doesn't imply that work is done in accelerating a body does it?
So is this definition of work wrong?

Comment: Which book is that?

Comment: This is a really bad definition.

Comment: @CuriousOne Atkin's Physical Chemistry

Comment: Let's put it this way: I would not define it in such a way in a text about mechanics. In this book they basically assume that you have gone trough the proper mechanical version of this and they want you to think about work in a slightly wider context than in mechanics and they want you to internalize that thermodynamics is about work done by systems on each other. In that sense it's not half as bad as it sounds when taken out of context. Moreover, technically there is no overlap between kinetic energy and thermodynamics, which can't really describe systems with macroscopic KE.

Comment: @CuriousOne Sure it can.  It's just that we usually leave out the change in KE of the system when we apply, say, the first law of thermodynamics to a system.  However, most texts at least start out by including KE in their formulation of the first law.  See, for example, Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics by Moran et al, or Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics by Smith and van Ness.

Comment: @ChesterMiller: One can not model the atmospheric entry of a spacecraft with thermodynamics alone. One can not model the flight of a Boeing 747 with thermodynamics, either. It doesn't have the necessary momentum transfer equations, it doesn't give you heat transfer coefficients etc.. A proper treatment of strong non-equilibrium conditions shows, by the way, that there is no self-consistent theory with a finite number of degrees of freedom for this case, at all.

Comment: @CuriouOne:  That was not my point at all.  I did not say that either the mechanical energy balance or the thermal energy balance could be used to model anything in science.  But, I do assert that the differential overall energy balance that is used to analyze Boeing 747 flight is derived directly on the basis of the open system (control volume) version of the first law of thermodynamics, which includes KE.  And the differential mechanical energy balance equation that is also part of the 747 analysis is obtained by dotting the equation of motion with the velocity vector, and also includes KE.

Comment: @CuriousOne : a bad thing still in this definition is "*opposing* force". Work may be positive or negative depending on the direction of force wrt displacement. And one has to emphasize the sign of work is a convention: I see English textbooks use $W>0$ if the system exerts work on the outside, when French courses use $W>0$ for incoming energy, just like $Q>0$ for incoming energy.

Comment: @ChesterMiller: You can assert that and it's simply not true. The first law of thermodynamics doesn't tell you anything about the flow around the body of the plane and in the engines. If you believe that it is, then you should derive all of continuum mechanics from the three laws of thermodynamics. Good luck with that. TD is exclusively modeling nearly homogenous systems and systems with macroscopic KE simply don't qualify.

Comment: @L.Levrel: I agree. I certainly wouldn't do it this way and mechanics textbooks take usually more care. I think it simply doesn't matter to these authors at this point. Whether that's good style is debatable.

Comment: @CuriousOne I thought I made it clear that the general transient *differential* form of the first law is both spatially and time dependent.  I never said that the system had to be homogeneous on the macroscopic scale.  Being a continuum mechanics guy myself, I'm pretty confident that the equations can be derived from the differential version of the first law energy balance, the differential version of Newton's 2nd law, and the rheological constitutive equation for the fluid (Newtonian, in the case of air).  And, I might add that I personally can derive these equations myself.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I think your statement "macroscopic KE don't qualify" is too broad. Some open and stationary systems may be modelled by thermodynamics, like a turbojet (to stay in the aeronautics field). "Model" doesn't mean "fully predict", but e.g. you can analyze the state of the gas given some input from fluid dynamics (like the pressure increase created by the fan as a function of its rotation speed).

Comment: @L.Levrel: Like I said, all you have to do to convince me is to derive the equations of fluid mechanics from the equations of thermodynamics. Did you actually try? Why not, it can't be that hard, right?

Comment: @CuriousOne: *I* did not say it can be done (reread my comment if necessary: I just said thermodynamics can be applied to some systems with macroscopic KE). Chester Miller did.

Comment: @L.Levrel: I am glad that you didn't say that, since it would have been 100% false. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The definition of work:

$$W=\int \vec F \cdot\mathrm{d}\vec x$$

So, work requires a force and a displacement. That is all. Think of it like this:

- If you push hard on a wall, you might use much effort to apply large force - but nothing moves and no work of use is done.
- If you push against a balloon, you can make it move very far. But you didn't really do much work because there was no effort in it since the force needed was so small.

In this sense, **work** makes sense in the every-day logical use of the term: You wouldn't call it work, unless it did a proper change (displacement) and required some amount of effort (force).

> My thermodynamics textbook defines work as follows.
>
> "Work is motion against an opposing force."

Simply **untrue**. Work is not motion (and what does that even mean? Meters per second?) I guess they mean *displacement*; but that is still an incomplete definition. Also, work is nothing "against" a force. A force might *do* work and forces might *counteract* each other - it doesn't make sense to say that work goes against a force.

> But this definition of work doesn't imply that work is done in accelerating a body does it?

And why should it? Work has got nothing to do with acceleration. Looking at the formula, it doesn't really matter how fast or how much the object accelerated while you pushed it. The only thing that matters is how hard you pushed (force) and how far (displacement).

An example is you pushing a car up a hill. At constant speed. No acceleration, but certainly a force exerted and a displacement happening.

Comment: if $W=\int \vec F \;\mathrm{d}\vec x$ and $\vec F=m \vec a$, then wouldn't $W=\int m \vec a \;\mathrm{d}\vec x$?  I'm having trouble thinking of a scenario where there is work being done but there is no acceleration.  Can you give an example?

Comment: An example: Me pushing my car up a hill at constant speed.

Comment: @jakemcgregor The expression $\vec F=m\vec a$ is incorrect - or at least not valid in general. There is no law that says this. Rather the expression is: $\sum \vec F=m\vec a$. The sum symbol $\sum$ might feel unnecessary, but it is of huge importance. The point is that **any** force might do work, and they can even do that while balancing each other out, resulting in no acceleration $\sum F=0$.

Comment: was your car initially moving at the same constant speed uphill prior to you pushing on it uphill?  For simplicity, I would think it (the car) would initially have a velocity of zero, and for you to get it to some constant speed would require you to accelerate your car, no?

Comment: @jakemcgregor It might. In that case **yes**, work was done while acceleration took place. But it also might not. The car could be rolling downhill into a valley and gaining speed, and then you might start pushing as it goes uphill, merely keeping the speed constant. Then **no**, work was done without acceleration. The point is that those two properties are unrelated. And so acceleration has got nothing to do in the definition of work.

Comment: OK, so going back to your first comment, $\sum \vec F=m\vec a$ and if forces are balanced then $\sum \vec F=0$.  If we substitute into the eqn. for work, wouldn't $W=\int \sum \vec F \;\mathrm{d}\vec x = \int 0 \;\mathrm{d}\vec x = 0$? (thanks for sticking with me to help me out)

Comment: @jakemcgregor No worries. Well, in Newton's 2nd law: $$\sum \vec F=m\vec a$$ the **sum** of all the present forces is inputted. When I push a wooden block up a hill, all forces here might be the push $P$, friction $f$ and weight $w$. So: $$\sum \vec F=\vec w + \vec P+ \vec f= m\vec a$$ Together they may cause an acceleration, as the law says. Now, each of these forces may do **work**! A force can do work - it is not the sum of forces, just each force.

Comment: @jakemcgregor You are in some sense right, though, since the sum of all work done might be zero. If I do positive work by pushing the block upwards (towards the positive displacement direction), then $\vec P$ did positive work. Friction $f$ pulls the other way and does negative work. Weight $w$ has a component pulling the other way as well and also does negative work. In total from the 1st law of thermodynamics: $$\Delta U=Q-W$$If no internal energy is gained and no heat is transfered, then the sum of all work must be zero - so they might equal. But that is only in this simple case.

Comment: Just as how I was mistaken about $\vec F=m\vec a$, and how really the relation is $\sum \vec F=m\vec a$, is it a mistake to say $W=\int \vec F \;\mathrm{d}\vec x$, and really the relation is $\sum W=\int \sum \vec F \;\mathrm{d}\vec x $ (work is a scalar, yes? how can it be positive or negative?)  Can you give an example that will result in the net work being a  value other than zero, where no acceleration occurred?

Comment: @jakemcgregor **(1)** The relation is $$W=\int \vec F \cdot \mathrm{d} \vec x$$ If the force you insert is the resulting (or sum) force $\sum F$, then you find the work done by that. **(2)** Work is a scalar yes. Note that there is a dot in the integral - work is namely the dot-product of force to displacement vectors. A dot-product gives a scalar and is *positive* if vectors point in the same direction and *negative* if they point oppositely. **(3)** I have already given such example; me pushing a car uphill - I use a force to displace the car at constant speed.

Comment: @jakemcgregor and Steeven re (3): the work-energy theorem and Newton's second law are mathematically equivalent. So no, you can't have nonzero net total work and zero acceleration simultaneously. Re (1): the confusion may come from the fact $W=\int F·dx$ is a mere *definition*, it cannot be true or false; whereas the 2nd law is a principle, it can be experimentally tested.

Answer (score 1):

A more general definition is ( the integral ) of force times distance.

A static force, eg a body resting on a surface , does no work.

The same body dropped has work done on it by the force caused by Gravity, potential energy being gradually converted to kinetic energy for the duration of the fall.

Comment: Your answer is right but misleading: make it clear that acceleration is *not* necessary for work to be done (which the OP seems to think). Give an example where there's no acceleration!

Comment: @L.Levrel if $W=\int \vec F \;\mathrm{d}\vec x$ and $\vec F=m \vec a$, then wouldn't $W=\int m \vec a \;\mathrm{d}\vec x$?  By definition, force causes only a change in velocity (an acceleration); it does not maintain the velocity, and for there to be work, there must be acceleration?

Comment: @jakemcgregor: see Steeven's comments, which I fully support.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a definition of work. You need to put on more context. If the author was talking about how to get the work calculated, it is fair to make this statement.